# How to ssh to a wordpress site

Tags: wordpress, ssh, ftp

I'm having trouble logging into my wordpress wp-admin page. When I go to http://example.com/wp-admin it redirects to a secure https https://example.com/wp-admin.php and says "Web page not available".

Wordpress is hosting the site, so I can't FTP into it. Trying to SSH into it using my Wordpress username and password isn't working either.

```
ssh user@example.com
password: Password
```

Results in: "Permission denied, please try again." Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Do you mean you have a site hosted with WordPress.com? If so, [they do not allow SSH or even FTP access](https://en.support.wordpress.com/ftp-access/). If you don't mean WordPress.com then you will need to contact your specific host for SSH instructions (and to see if they even allow it)

Comment: Yes, I mean WordPress.com... so if they don't allow SSH or FTP, am I kind of screwed?

Comment: Not necessarily. Can you access the public facing side of your site using HTTPS?

Comment: Nope, it's the same problem saying "Web page not available". But regular http works fine.

Comment: Is your domain something like `XXX.wordpress.com` or do you have your own domain? For that former, SSL should be enabled on the server and it should just work. For the latter, I'm not sure if they offer that as an option.

Comment: It's the latter unfortunately...

Comment: My understanding is that WP.com does not offer HTTPS support for custom domains but I would confirm this with their support people. As a work-around you could use a reverse proxy such as CloudFlare that will give you the SSL part although I'm not sure if there's any issue with WP.com

Comment: CloudFlare helped solve it! Thank you! Feel free to post that as an answer & I'll accept it as solved :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*(comments converted to an answer)*

WordPress.com [doesn't support direct access for SSH or FTP](https://en.support.wordpress.com/ftp-access/). Also, as far as I can tell, they only support HTTPS when using subdomains of wordpress.com, not custom domains.

However, if you're looking for a way to get HTTPS in front of your site but your host doesn't support it, one alternative is to put a reverse proxy such as CloudFlare in front of your site. CloudFlare offers free TLS (SSL) termination so users will connect to CloudFlare's server securely, CloudFlare will decrypt their information and then transparently pass that on to your origin server.

Answer (score 0):

No SSH access, nor FTP, but if you just need to fiddle with files, how about using **SFTP**?

As per [WordPress.com Support](https://en.support.wordpress.com/sftp/), SFTP access **is** available to Administrators of sites on WordPress.com's Business and eCommerce plans.

If you are on one of the other plans, and want SFTP access, you can upgrade your site from your [plans page](https://wordpress.com/plans/).